# Creating Tabs Dynamically in code - Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs

I am having the hardest time understanding the Studio 3.5 Tabbed Activity template. So to follow along, simply open a new project with Studio 3.5 and select Tabbed Activity as your starting template.

I need an activity, in this simple example, that adds a new TAB and passes info to the PlaceholderFragment class object, and sets the Tab title. Each tab will use the same fragment.xml layout. And will populate the contents based on data passed from the main activity. It won't start with any Tabs initially. For this example, let's assume that each time you press the Floating Button in the template that it adds a new TAB.

Can someone show me how this should be wired up? I simply can't figure it out by looking at the template which hard codes the number of Tabs and the Tab titles. I seem to have a complete mental block on this design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - figured it out, so going to answer my specific question so others can learn.

This page helped me figure it out. It is written in Kotlin, and I am using Java; but no problem translating.
https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-tablayout-with-many-tabs-kotlin/

- Do not modify either XML file that the template creates.
- No modification to PageViewModel.java (I still don't know how to use that and probably not needed in this exercise.
- Do not modify the PlaceholderFragment.java
- My modifications to MainActivity.java and SectionsPagerAdapter.java are below and self-explanatory.

  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  ```
  private final Context mContext;
  ArrayList<String> tabNames = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

  public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
      mContext = context;
  }

  public void add(Fragment fragment, String title) {
      tabNames.add(title);
      fragments.add(fragment);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return fragments.get(position);
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return tabNames.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return fragments.size();
  }
  ```

  }

And for MainActivity.java, just use this code in the FloatingActionButton,onClickListener to add a new Tab.

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int curCount = sectionsPagerAdapter.getCount();
            sectionsPagerAdapter.add(PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(curCount),
                    "TAB " + String.valueOf(curCount));
            sectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

That is all it takes.

Comment: In addition, as I cannot figure out what the PageViewModel does in this scenario, I found that I can completely remove this Class for use. I know - this is probably obvious to many of you, but I have never seen it. I know about ViewModel development but I can't see my way clear to why in this case. Easy to pass data from the MainActivity, in this example, to the Frament.newInstance() method, stick it in the Bundle and save it as a field in the onCreate() method of the Fragment.